# There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm trying to access the response of my POST request in Postman via Post Request Script.

I added this 2 lines, under `Pre-request Script`

```
let response = pm.response.json(); 
console.log('JSON Response: ',response );
```

Then, I opened up my Postman console, before hit `Send` to make my POST request

I kept getting

> There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Do I need to enable anything on Postman?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Pre-request scripts are ran before the request is sent. You do not have a response yet.

Try putting your script under the `Tests` tab, which is ran after a response is received.

Comment: ohh, crap, you're right. I missed interpret while reading this post : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#defining-collection-variables

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there was a script that was screwing up my request.  If you get the postman collection from someone else, check this and try to fix it. (in my case I don't need it so I deleted it)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting an environment variable, get it and parse it, I was created a POST requests to make a login and get a token to each request.

```
const echoPostRequest = {
  url: pm.environment.get("url_login"),
  method: 'POST',
  header: 'Content-Type: application/json',
  body: {
    mode: 'raw',
    raw: JSON.stringify({ email: pm.environment.get("user"),password: pm.environment.get("password") })
  }
};
pm.sendRequest(echoPostRequest, function (err, res) {
    console.log(err ? err : res.json());
    pm.environment.set("login_response", res.json());
    pm.environment.set("bearer_token", pm.environment.get("login_response").bearer_token);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

was helping a friend and he had tried to make an adjustment to all requests in the collection.

I found in the documentation, how to remove

https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you added lines are correct but you need to put them in the Tests tab because Pre-request Scripts are run before executing code. If you need to do something before running code add it in Pre-request Scripts tab If you work with response you have to add those lines in Tests tab[image: Pre-request Scripts tab, Tests tab ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

You might entered your snippet in the pre-request tab instead of test tab.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Or find a different way of phrasing which looks more like providing an explained solution than some kind of speculation. I.e. if this is true, what does it mean? How does it cause the observed problem? What to do to fix the problem? Why does that help? More or less as described in [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Please Make Sure That You Cleared Text Area Of PRE-REQUEST & TESTS TAB

By Clearing Text I Solved This Issue

Comment: Well, what if you need a pre request script?

Answer (score -5):

Check if you SSL was turn off. If isn't, turn off.

Settings >> General  >> SSL Certificate Verification

Comment: Well, turning it off actually solved my problem.