# Getting response from Postman in script

Tags: javascript, postman

[image: image attached]I want to get the value of token from response of Postman and set it to an environment.

My response is showing like :

```js
{
  "success": true,
  "token": "ojkdd"
}
```

and my script is :

```js
pm.test(responseBody, true)
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData)
```

I get the following error :

```js
ReferenceError: responseBody is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429643/there-was-an-error-in-evaluating-the-pre-request-script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your json data is in pm.
So you need to retrieve your JSON data using the below code.

```
 var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 

 pm.test("Verify Json values", function () { 
  pm.expect(jsonData.success).is.to.equal(true); 
 });
```

Edit : For setting it to environment as @danny suggested

```
 pm.environment.set("token", pm.response.json().token)
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following error from the first line: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined"

Comment: did you console.log(pm.response.json().token) ? Sometimes the environment would be set even though postman throws undefined error.

Comment: screenshot attached in question.

Comment: By the way I used POST method, sending username and password from the body as json and in response I get success and token

Comment: Refer the answer to this question for your pre requisite script issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429643/there-was-an-error-in-evaluating-the-pre-request-script

Comment: You can only use `pm.response.json()` in the `Tests` tab as that's when it would know what the response will be. The items in the `Pre-request Script` tab get actioned **before** the main request is sent.

Comment: You mean like this: console.log(pm.test(pm.response.json()))

Comment: No, you can **only** use the `pm.response.json()` function in the `Tests` tab of the app. It will not work in the `Pre-request Script` tab.

Answer (score 2):

You did this same wrong way as I today :D the script should be in **`test`** not in `Pre-request Sript`

For response:
{
"token" : "kj32n4jk32n4"
}

Past below script to **TEST** tab in postman and debug it in postman console

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody)
console.log(data.token)
postman.setEnvironmentVariable('token',data.token)
```

Comment: is that your own token ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the value as an `environment` variable, you can add this to the `Tests` tab:

```
pm.environment.set("token", pm.response.json().token)
```

You will need to ensure that you have created an environment file and it's selected in the top right of the UI, before the variable can be stored.

More information about storing variables can be found here:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/#defining-variables-in-scripts